# Sqlite UPSERT and retrieve matching row

Tags: sqlite

I am trying to load data from a csv file into a more normalized database structure.

Reduced example, consider a list of people with their address (number, street, city). More than one person may live at an address but each person only has one home. I have the following temporary table containing data loaded from a CSV file:

```
CREATE TABLE temp (name TEXT, houseNo INTEGER, street TEXT, city TEXT);
INSERT INTO temp VALUES('Mr Benn',52,'Festive Road','London');
INSERT INTO temp VALUES('Prime Minister',10,'Downing Street','London');
INSERT INTO temp VALUES('Mrs Benn',52,'Festive Road','London');
INSERT INTO temp VALUES('Baby Benn',52,'Festive Road','London');
INSERT INTO temp VALUES('Reggie Perrin',12,'Coleridge Close','London');
INSERT INTO temp VALUES('Larry The Cat',10,'Downing Street','London');
```

I want to load up these tables:

```
CREATE TABLE people(name TEXT PRIMARY KEY);
CREATE TABLE addresses(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, houseNo INTEGER, street TEXT, city TEXT,UNIQUE(houseNo,street,city) );
CREATE TABLE homes(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT NOT NULL, addressId INTEGER NOT NULL,FOREIGN KEY (name) REFERENCES people(name), FOREIGN KEY (addressId) REFERENCES addresses(id));
```

So for each row in 'temp' I want to:

1. INSERT the `name` into the `people` table
2. UPSERT the address fields into `addresses` and **get back the `id`** (whether new or existing), and
3. use this `id` to INSERT a row in the `homes` table

I can write this:

```
INSERT INTO people SELECT name FROM temp;
INSERT INTO addresses(houseNo,street,city) SELECT houseNo,street,city FROM temp WHERE TRUE ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING;
INSERT INTO homes(name,addressId) SELECT t.name,a.id FROM addresses a, temp t WHERE a.houseNo = t.houseNo AND a.street = t.street AND a.city=t.city;
SELECT * FROM homes
```

which does the job:

```
id      name    addressId
--      ----    ---------
1       Mr Benn         1
2       Prime Minister  2
3       Mrs Benn        1
4       Baby Benn       1
5       Reggie Perrin   3
6       Larry The Cat   2
```

But using this, *I am running through the temp table 3 times* (my actual dataset is much larger, and has more columns). It seems inefficient as I know the `id` used in Step 3 already from Step 2.

**Is there a more performant way to achieve my goal in Sqlite?**

Answer (score 1):

**Solution 1: Use a VIEW and an INSTEAD OF trigger**

Define temp as a VIEW and create a TRIGGER to redirect INSERTs into TEMP to INSERTs into the other tables

```
CREATE VIEW temp AS 
   SELECT name, houseNo, street, city
   from homes join addresses on (homes.addressID = addresses.id);

CREATE TRIGGER temp_trigger
INSTEAD OF INSERT ON temp 
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO people (name) VALUES (NEW.name);
   INSERT OR IGNORE INTO addresses (houseNo,street,city) VALUES (NEW.houseNo, NEW.street, NEW.city);
   INSERT INTO homes (name,addressId) VALUES (NEW.name, (SELECT a.id FROM addresses a WHERE a.houseNo = NEW.houseNo AND a.street = NEW.street AND a.city = NEW.city));
END;
```

Then you can proceed to load your temp table from the CSV.

PRO: Your tables will be populated in a single pass while you are importing your data, without even the need of storing the temp table.

CON: For every row, you need to search the address table for the ID of the address, because you have no way in pure SQL to use the value you just inserted (or ignored).

**Solution 2: Use "fast" temp table**

While your original solution can be slow for large input files, you can squeeze the most from Sqlite by leveraging the temp schema:

```
PRAGMA temp_store = MEMORY;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp (name TEXT, houseNo INTEGER, street TEXT, city TEXT);
```

Then proceed with loading your data from CSV and then populating the other tables with your original queries.

With this syntax the TEMPORARY table temp will be created in memory (and dropped when the connection closes), so even if you are loading it from CSV and running through it 3 times, it will still be faster than a normal table.

PRO: Simplest solution, easily adaptable to many scenarios where you need to load external data and manipulate it before storing in its final form.

CON: Depending on size of data and type of manipulation, this could be faster or slower than Solution #1.

Of course, in both solutions, wrapping all the data loading in a single transaction will speed up things a lot.